# No element is shown until sys.exit(app.exec_())

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I try to show pictures (max.6) on a window. Before that you have to enter a name in the first Window (not given in the following code).
The pictures are automatically transferred from my camera to the computer so at the beginning no picture will be in the folder but after some time maybe until 6.
By running the code no error appears but the window olny loads completly when all 6 images are in the correct folder. So nothing is shown until `sys.exit(app.exec_())` has run.

I tried to call `sys.exit(app.exec_())` after `ui.update_picture(MainWindow)` but then the skript stops at this point.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import sys
import os
import time


path = "C:/Users/benni/Desktop/"                   # given from the first Window
folder_name = "exit_folder_test"                   # given from the first Window
source = "test"                                    # given
os.makedirs(path + folder_name)



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        start_x = 20                                # origin from the grid
        start_y = 80                                
        distance = 40                               # distance between the pictures
        global image_width
        image_width = 600                                                       
        global image_height
        image_height = 400

        self.picture1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)                                         # all the different fields for the pictures, grid-layout
        self.picture1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(start_x, start_y, image_width, image_height))

        self.picture2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.picture2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x + image_width + distance), start_y, image_width, image_height))

        self.picture3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.picture3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x + 2*image_width + 2*distance), start_y, image_width, image_height))

        self.picture4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.picture4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x), (start_y + image_height + distance), image_width, image_height))

        self.picture5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.picture5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x + image_width + distance), (start_y + image_height + distance), image_width, image_height))

        self.picture6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.picture6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x + 2*image_width + 2*distance), (start_y + image_height + distance), image_width, image_height))

        self.print_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)       
        self.print_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect((start_x + 3*image_width + 2*distance) - 74, (start_y + 2*image_height + 2*distance), 75, 24)) 
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def update_picture(self, MainWindow):                               # funktions to add pictures to the fields in setupUi
        pixmap1 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image1.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture1.setPixmap(pixmap1)
        pixmap2 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image2.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture2.setPixmap(pixmap2)
        pixmap3 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image3.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture3.setPixmap(pixmap3)
        pixmap4 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image4.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture4.setPixmap(pixmap4)
        pixmap5 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image5.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture5.setPixmap(pixmap5)
        pixmap6 = QPixmap(path + folder_name + "/image6.jpg").scaled(image_width, image_height)
        self.picture6.setPixmap(pixmap6)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Fotobox"))
        self.print_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "print"))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    recording = True
    amount = 0
    number = 0
    while recording == True:
        pictures = os.listdir(path + source)         # reads the content of the given folder
        amount_update = len(pictures)         
        if amount != amount_update:                  # checks if the amount of files in the folder has changed
            amount = amount_update 
            for picture_name in pictures:                 
                number += 1
                time.sleep(1)                                   # wait until the picture is transferred
                picture_new_name = "image" + str(number) + ".jpg"
                os.rename(path + source + "/" + picture_name, path + folder_name + "/" + picture_new_name)   # renames all the given pictures and transfer them in a new folder
                if number > 0 and number < 7:           
                    ui.update_picture(MainWindow)
                    print(number)
                else:
                    recording = False
            recording = False



    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not have to do with app.exec_(), the problem is that you have a task that blocks the GUI preventing it from displaying correctly, so in this case you must run that task in another thread and notify the GUI through signals:

```py
import os
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


path = "C:/Users/benni/Desktop/"  # given from the first Window
folder_name = "exit_folder_test"  # given from the first Window
source = "test"
extension = "jpg"

if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, folder_name)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, folder_name))


class PictureWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def search(self):
        recording = True
        number = 0
        amount = 0
        while recording:
            pictures = []
            for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, source)):
                if file.endswith(".{}".format(extension)):
                    pictures.append(file)
            amount_update = len(pictures)
            if (
                amount != amount_update
            ):  # checks if the amount of files in the folder has changed
                amount = amount_update
                for picture_name in pictures:
                    number += 1
                    time.sleep(1)  # wait until the picture is transferred
                    picture_new_name = "image{}.{}".format(number, extension)
                    os.rename(
                        os.path.join(path, source, picture_name),
                        os.path.join(path, folder_name, picture_new_name),
                    )  # renames all the given pictures and transfer them in a new folder
                    if 0 < number < 7:
                        print(number)
                        self.updateSignal.emit()
                    else:
                        recording = False
                recording = False


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
        rows, cols = 2, 3
        self._labels = []
        image_width, image_height = 600, 400

        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setFixedSize(image_width, image_height)
                grid_layout.addWidget(label, row, col)
                self._labels.append(label)

        self.print_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("print")
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.print_button, 3, 3)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)

    def update_image(self):
        for i, label in enumerate(self._labels):
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(
                os.path.join(
                    path, folder_name, "image{}.{}".format(i + 1, extension)
                )
            )
            label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    worker = PictureWorker()
    worker.updateSignal.connect(w.update_image)
    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    thread.start()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, worker.search)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Octarock If my answer will help you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour] :-)

Comment: @Octarock mmmm,,